# Adding a Trailing Slash to all URLs in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

It appears as if Magento 2 removes the trailing slash by default. Is there any way to change that? I'm trying to find the code that redirects that within the .htaccess file. Whenever I add the following code there is just a large redirect chain that causes the site to slow down.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]

I want trailing slash at the end of all my URLs. **https://www.example.com/category/**. Currently, they redirect to non-trailing slashes https://www.example.com/category

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for Category/Product URLs:

> Stores --> Settings --> Configuration --> Catalog --> Catalog -->
>   Search Engine Optimization --> Category URL Suffix

Set the value to:

> /

Trying it on a dev environment first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution to append a trailing slash and also if you want to skip for the particular module to append a trailing slash in both cases you can use this code update logic according to your requirement.

First create event file.

**app/code/[Custom_Module]/[Module_Name]/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="add_slash_in_url" instance="[Custom_Module]/[Module_Name]\Observer\PredispathActionControllerObserver" />
    </event>
```

create observer file.
**app/code/[Custom_Module]/[Module_Name]/Observer/PredispathActionControllerObserver.php**

```
<?php
namespace [Custom_Module]\[Module_Name]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

/**
 * Class Predispath Frontend Action Controller Observer
 */
class PredispathActionControllerObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlInterface;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var []
     */
    protected $skipModule = [
        'cms',
        'cms_page',
        'cms_block',
        'catalog'
    ];

    /**
     * @param UrlInterface $urlInterface
     * @param ActionFlag $actionFlag
     */
    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        ActionFlag $actionFlag
    ) {
        $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    }

    /**
     * Execute Observer
     *
     * @param  \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $currentUrl = $this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
        $result = explode('?', $currentUrl);
        $result[0] = trim($result[0], '/') . '/';
        $urlSlash = implode('?', $result);

        if ($urlSlash != $currentUrl) {
            $controller = $observer->getEvent()->getData('controller_action');
            if (empty($controller) || !is_object($controller) || !$controller ||
                !method_exists($controller, 'getRequest') ||
                empty($controller->getRequest()) || !$controller->getRequest() ||
                empty($controller->getRequest()->getModuleName()) || !$controller->getRequest()->getModuleName() ||
                in_array($controller->getRequest()->getModuleName(), $this->skipModule)) {
                return;
            }
            if ($controller->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()
                || $controller->getRequest()->isPost()
            ) {
                return;
            }
            $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($urlSlash, 301)->sendResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 way to solve your issue:

1. You can try adding the following code to your .htaccess file:

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
2. Magento 2 provides a configuration setting for adding trailing slashes. In the admin panel, go to `Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Search Engine Optimization` and set the "**Add Store Code to Urls**" and "**Auto-redirect to Base URL**" options appropriately.